# What is the best technique to delete a file during concurrent reading to this file?

Tags: c++, linux, file

I need to support a class that has methods like:

1. int read_file_with_offset(fd, offset)
2. bool delete_file(fd)

The read API above will be called frequently.

The expected behavior is: when delete API is not called, threads can use the read API concurrently. When the delete API is called, the readers before delete API should still be able to complete successfully, but the readers after the delete API should get an error code such as "inaccessible".

Is the linux file system already able to handle this? Or we have to use some in-memory concurrent data structure to achieve this?

Comment: On Linux, you can delete a file anytime, it has no effect on opened file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best technique to delete a file during concurrent reading to this file?

The best technique to delete a file during any I/O is to delete the file. There is no other technique.

Deleting a file only removes the link to the file from the directory inode. It has no effect on any I/O operations. Open fd still refer to the file, you can still use them with no problem. The file is finally "removed" when all file descriptors that refer to the file are closed. It is typical to create a temporary file, open it, and `unlink()` it right after creation.

> the readers after the delete API should get an error code such as "inaccessible".

Check if the file exists before reading.

```
int read_file_with_offset(fd, offset) {
   struct stat stat;
   if (fstatat(fd, &stat) == -1) {
       return inaccessible;
   }
   ...
}
```

A faster way would be to just create your own bool variable that signifies that a specific fd has been removed or not.

Comment: I think your explaination is true only for linux, not for windows.

Comment: So the answer was not matching the question before the linux tag was added.

Comment: @gerum: You are correct that the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76248677/1) was not tagged `linux`. However, inside the text of the question, the original question did specifically ask about Linux. Therefore, this answer does match the original question.